# Integration of a bivariate domain to obtain the cumulative distribution of a bivariate function

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, definite-integrals, cumulative-distribution-functions

Compute the (cumulative) probability function of $U = Y_1 - Y_2$, given that the joint density probability function $f(y_1, y_2)$ is

$$
\begin{align}
f(y_1, y_2) &= e^{-y_1} \qquad \text{in} \qquad 0 \leq y_2 \leq y_1 \leq \infty \\
f(y_1, y_2) &= 0 \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{elsewhere}
\end{align}
$$

I get different results depending if I first integrate over $Y_1$, or over $Y_2$:

- $Y_1$-inner integration:
  $$
  F_a(u) = P(Y_1 - Y_2 \leq u) = P(Y_1 \leq Y_2 + u) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\int_{y_2}^{y_2+u} e^{- y_1} d y_1 \right) d y_2 = 1 - e^{-u}
  $$
- $Y_2$-inner integration:
  $$
  F_b(u) = P(Y_2 \geq Y_1 - u) = \int_{u}^{\infty} \left( \int_{y_1 - u}^{y_1} e^{- y_1} d y_2 \right) d y_1 = u e^{-u} 
  $$

How to correct the integration boundaries of one of the above, so that $F_a = F_b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_a(u)$ is correct. For $F_b(u)$, you missed another term, which is

$\int_0^u\left(\int_0^{y_1}e^{-y_1} dy_2\right) dy_1 = 1-e^{-u}-ue^{-u}$.

Comment: It should be $F_a(u) = F_b(u)$, so first integral of $F_b$ should have boundaries $\int_0^{\infty}$. But then why the new constraint $Y_2 \geq Y_1 - u$ gets no use at all?

Comment: .. no, my correction in the comment above is wrong. But still it should be $F_a = F_b$.

Comment: Of course, $F_b(u)$ and $F_a(u)$ should be equal.  $F_b(u)$ has two terms, one is  $1-e^{-u}-ue^{-u}$, another one is $ue^{-u}$. Their sum is $1-e^{-u}$, exactly the same as $F_a(u)$.

Comment: I see it now! I should have sketched the domain of integration on a piece of paper first.